# Can I store user bank details without PCI compliance?

Tags: pci-compliance, pci-dss, banking

We are working on a project its nature is somewhat ride sharing , I read about PCI Compliance i know we have to be PCI Compliance if we are dealing with credit card or payment i am a little ambiguous do we store our drivers bank info like Account number(encrypted) , Account title etc in database , i have read about

**Who must be PCI compliant?**
"If you accept credit cards from your customers, then you must be PCI compliant" [reference](https://www.spreedly.com/pci/)

so if we store only bank account numbers not credit card
we must have to be PCI compliance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Yes it is !! there are numerous post on PCI Compliance there.

Comment: #stackoverflow is to help developers ,this is not only for programming question.

Comment: thousands of question there for pci-dss https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pci-dss

Comment: no but it wouldn't hurt; it's sensitive data, treat it as such

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to be PCI compliant as, you already have pointed out, that you do not handle credit card information. PCI DSS, which standards for Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard, only governs credit card data. ACH/Bank account information clearly does not fall under their purview.

However, there are rules around ACH/Bank account data governed by NACHA. You *do* fall under their scope and must obey [their standards](https://www.nacha.org/rules). So, essentially, there are a set of standards similar to PCI that must follow. So if you were hoping to avoid scrutiny and regulation you are out of luck.

You also may be governed by the laws of where your data is stored as well as where you operate. You would need to speak to a lawyer to get more information about that.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Refer to the NACHA rulebook for the data security standards you need to comply with.